# Sql function find date difference between two consecutive rows per group

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on clinical data to find total sessions for patients by finding date difference. I can achieve this using Python but power bi does not support that script. So I needed help to do this in SQL. I am basic level user of SQL so have no idea how to start for this.

Below is raw data

| PatientID | SessionDate |
| --- | --- |
| 264 | 5/26/2021 |
| 264 | 5/27/2021 |
| 264 | 5/28/2021 |
| 264 | 5/19/2021 |
| 264 | 5/20/2021 |
| 264 | 5/21/2021 |
| 264 | 5/24/2021 |
| 264 | 5/25/2021 |
| 264 | 5/17/2021 |
| 264 | 5/18/2021 |
| 281 | 5/18/2021 |
| 281 | 5/25/2021 |
| 281 | 6/29/2021 |
| 281 | 6/1/2021 |
| 281 | 4/16/2020 |
| 281 | 4/23/2020 |
| 281 | 4/21/2020 |
| 281 | 4/28/2020 |
| 281 | 4/30/2020 |
| 281 | 5/5/2020 |
| 281 | 10/16/2019 |

Expected output is as below

[image: Expected Data]

Comment: `DATEDIFF(date, LAG(date))`

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks !

Comment: Hi @Akina, I was able to get the result. But there is one problem. My date column has timestamp in it. I use Cast to convert it to date. But I am unable to use it inside LAG function so it gives value 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 instead of Zero. Can you please suggest how to resolve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide your source data not as a table but as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: @Akina. Thank you for guiding me in correct direction. I was able to built a query which gave me required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Akina hint I was able to get the required output from following query
Note:- My **sessionDate** column was in Date and timestamp format.

```
select
        t.PatientID,

        CAST(t.SessionTimestamp as Date) as SessionDate,

        LAG(t.SessionTimestamp) over(partition by t.PatientRecordId order by t.PatientID,t.SessionTimestamp) as Next_Date  


from mytable t

order by
t.PatientID,
t.SessionTimestamp
```